# Regex ignore a pattern

Tags: c#, regex, csv

I am trying to figure out a viable way to go about parsing this CSV file. Currently I am using filehelpers which is great. But with this csv file it seems to be having issues.

Each record in the the csv file is contained in quotes and delimited by a comma.
The records have commas within them and 1 record out of the 90,000 records im dealing with has one single " that mucks up the Readline.

The record looks like this "24" Blah     ",

So I'm looking to write a regex to insert into the BeforeReadRecord that will go through and replace all instances of " with a space.

I'm newer to regex but I'm not finding any way to exclude three cases.
Case one: each line starts with a "
Case two: each line ends with a "
Case three: each field is separated by ","

I am trying to figure out how I could exclude those three cases and be left to just replace any straggler " .

So far I've been failing miserably and am not even sure if there is a way to accomplish this. Perhaps someone knows of a better csv parser that handles this one odd case as well?

EDIT: Well here's what I ended up with. It takes a little time to process(also just changes any outlier " to ' which is fine since the data that contains quotes is needed for any queries) but looking for any pitfalls I may be falling in to make it faster but it seemed to be the quickest solution so far(took about 7 seconds for 92,000 records) but there doesn't seem any way around checking every line so... My previous solution was a nasty nested if that seemed to 30 seconds or so over the course of processing the records. It accounts for all scenarios except for where someone decides to put a random ", at the end of a field... hoping I don't run into a record like this but it wouldn't surprise me.

```
in its own method{
    engine.BeforeReadRecord += (sender, args) =>
                args.RecordLine = checkQuote(args.RecordLine);
                var records = engine.ReadFile(reportFilePath);
}

private static string checkQuote(string checkString)
        {
            if (checkString.Substring(0, 1) == @"""")
            {
                string removeQuote = @"""" + checkString.Replace(@"""", "'").Replace(@"','", @""",""").Remove(checkString.Length-1,1).Remove(0,1) + @"""";
                return removeQuote;
            }
            else
                return checkString; }
```

Comment: please show what you have tried.

Comment: alright but it's no where near close
    'FileHelperEngine<AKDetailReader> engine = new                          FileHelperEngine<AKDetailReader>();

            engine.BeforeReadRecord += (sender, args) =>
            args.RecordLine = Regex.Replace(args.RecordLine, @"(?!"","")""", "");
            var records = engine.ReadFile(reportFilePath);'

Comment: is there anyway to exclude those in a pattern though and only grab " that do not fit in those patterns?

Comment: you could have easily wrote a conditional check vs banging your head that meets the condition that you are looking for.. and then continued on with splitting the file

Comment: @user3776809 Please edit that code into your question, so it gets the benefit of formatting as well as context.

Answer (score 1):

File format readers typically don't handle malformed input well. Why should they? If you give a CSV reader bad data, I would *expect* it to barf. I've rarely had good luck with computer software that makes assumptions about what I meant.

Do you really need a regular expression? If you define a straggler as the last quote character when the number is odd, then it's trivial to remove the last one: just count them and if the number is odd, remove the last one.

For example:

```
var quoteCount = inputString.Count(c => c == '\"');
if ((quoteCount % 2) == 1)
{
    inputString = inputString.Remove(inputString.LastIndexOf('\"'));
}
```

Done and done.

You could also do it in a single pass with a loop, but that's probably overkill. I strongly suspect that sanitizing the input is not a major bottleneck in your program.

For more complex patterns (i.e. you're looking for `","` or for a quote at the start and end, you just write a simple state machine. It's probably a dozen lines of code.

I realize that you might be able to do this with regular expressions. I find regex great for finding stuff and doing simple replacements. For more complicated rules like "replace quote with space unless the quote is at the beginning or end of line or next to a comma", I find it hard to come up with a good expression. For example, what about this case:

```
"first name","last name","","phone"
```

You have to take that blank field (i.e. "") into account. You also have to take into account spaces between fields (i.e. `"first"   ,   "last"   ,   ""`), and a whole host of other things. I'm reasonably sure that regex can do it. My experience has been that I can usually write the simple state machine and prove that it's correct faster than I can puzzle out the required regex. And it's certain that I'll more easily understand the state machine six months later.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the need for a regular expression is because the straggler quote could be anywhere. The text is formatted in the csv as such

"First Record","Second Record","Third Record","For"th Record" as you can see I am just trying to figure out cases that are like the fourth record

Comment: @user3776809: See my update. You can write a simple state machine for that.